# how to handle winrar diagnostic messages from code

Tags: c#, winforms, process, winrar

I am developing an windows application in that application i use winrar command line utility to make rar files.

### Code

```
public static string RarFiles(string rarPackagePath,
        Dictionary<int, string> accFiles)
    {
        string error = "";
        try
        {
            string[] files = new string[accFiles.Count];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var fList_item in accFiles)
            {
                files[i] = "\"" + fList_item.Value;
                i++;
            }
            string fileList = string.Join("\" ", files);
            fileList += "\"";
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo sdp = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            string cmdArgs = string.Format("A {0} {1} -ep1 -r",
                String.Format("\"{0}\"", rarPackagePath),
                fileList);
            sdp.ErrorDialog = true;
            sdp.UseShellExecute = true;
            sdp.Arguments = cmdArgs;
            sdp.FileName = winrarPath;//Winrar.exe path
            sdp.CreateNoWindow = false;
            sdp.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sdp);
            process.WaitForExit();
            //string s = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            error = "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;
        }
        return error;
    }
```

Can any one tell me how can i handle winrar diagnostic messages.

Comment: Why did you comment out the line where the standard output is saved in string s? There should be every output from winRar stored.

Comment: Because string s is always blank.When ever there is some error in making rar with winrar.exe it shows diagnostic message and returns nothing in process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

Answer (score 0):

i think u missed some parts :

try adding these :

```
sdp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

after Start, add a string to get the output. After that, call WaitForExit()

```
sdp.Start();
string output = stillc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
sdp.WaitForExit();
```

*Note : This works only if an output is shown in the console window.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: For this i need to set sdp.UseShellExecute = false;Which shows the executable windows.And i don't want to show that windows.By the way it still shows blank output